# Render issue with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm facing a problem I cannot get my head around. Server side I generate HTML code using Node.JS and JADE:

```
table#login-table.table.condensed
    tbody
        tr(ng-repeat="item in dailyTodoItems")
            td
                input(name="dailyTask", type="checkbox", ng-model="item.done", ng-change="todoChecked('{{item.id}}', '{{item.done}}')")
            td {{item.description}}
            td
                a(href="" ng-click="dailyTodoRemoveTask('{{item.id}}')") d
```

If you see line 5 (Input field) and the last line (a(href...) I use the same way to bind my items with Angular. The problem is that one works the other ( a(href... ) does not.
As you can see I call two JS functions:

```
$scope.todoChecked = function(id, done) {
    alert('change = ' + id);
};


$scope.dailyTodoRemoveTask = function(id) {
    alert('remove = ' + id);
};
```

`todoChecked()` returns the ID as it should but
`dailyTodoRemoveTask()` returns: `{{item.id}}`

The really strange thing is the when I inspect the code i the browser id do not see `{{item.id}}` but the correct ID for both places.
Any help will be appreciated. Below you see the full client JS code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var messages = [];
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var field = document.getElementById("field");
    var sendButton = document.getElementById("send");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");

    socket.on('history', function (data) {
        if(data.message) {
            messages.push(data.message);
            var html = '';
            for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                html += messages[i] + '<br />';
            }
            content.innerHTML = html;
        } else {
            console.log("There is a problem:", data);
        }
    });

    sendButton.onclick = function() {
        var text = field.value;
        socket.emit('send', { message: text, token: token });
    };

    socket.emit('send', { message: "Login: " + token });

});

//
// Allegro
//

var AllegroApp = angular.module('Allegro', []);

AllegroApp.controller('dailyTodoController', function($scope, $http) {

    // Model

    $scope.dailyTodoItems = [];
    $scope.newDailyTodoItem = '';



        // Load daily todo items
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/todo/get/12",
            data: {tkn: token}

        }).success(function(data, status) {
            // Push the data to the Model
            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {

                $scope.dailyTodoItems.push({
                    description: data.result[i].task,
                    done: data.result[i].done,
                    id: data.result[i]._id
                });
            }

        }).error(function(data, status) {
            // TODO handle error gracefully
            alert('Technical error: Could not save new daily todo task. Please try again :-( ');
        });




    // Events

    $scope.addDailyTodoItem = function() {
        // Check for empty input
        if ($scope.newDailyTodoItem.length < 1) { return; }


        // Update the database
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/todo/new/" + $scope.newDailyTodoItem,
            data: {tkn: token}

        }).success(function(data, status) {
            // Push the data to the Model
            $scope.dailyTodoItems.push({
                description: $scope.newDailyTodoItem,
                done: false,
                id: data.id
            });

        }).error(function(data, status) {
            // TODO handle error gracefully
            alert('Technical error: Could not save new daily todo task. Please try again :-( ');
        });
    };


    $scope.todoChecked = function(id, done) {
        alert('change = ' + id);
        if (done == 'true') { var newStatus = 'false' } else newStatus = 'true';
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/todo/update/' + id + '/' + newStatus,
            data: {tkn: token}
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            // UI already updated. No need to do anything
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            // TODO handle error gracefully
            alert('Technical error: Could not update task status. Please try again :-( ');
        });
    };


    $scope.dailyTodoRemoveTask = function(id) {
        alert('remove = ' + id);
    };


    $scope.todoLoadTodaysTasks = function() {

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you dont't have to interpolated model values inside directive. Please check this code.

```
table#login-table.table.condensed
    tbody
        tr(ng-repeat="item in dailyTodoItems")
            td
                input(name="dailyTask", type="checkbox", ng-model="item.done", ng-change="todoChecked(item.id, item.done)")
            td {{item.description}}
            td
                a(href="" ng-click="dailyTodoRemoveTask(item.id)") d
```